# Select A-Z from a list

Tags: list, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, alphabetical

I have a list of items and would like to give the user the option of jumping to the letter they want.

For example, the letters A-Z along the top of the screen, when the user clicks on B, it takes them to the part of the list with the first item beginning with B.

Is there any way to do this using ColdFusion?

My list is populated using a query.

```
<table border="1"> 
  <tr> 
    <th>Names</th> 
    <th>Other Stuff</th> 
  </tr> 

<cfoutput query="getnames"> 
  <tr> 
    <td> 
      <li>#getnames.names#</li> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
    <li>#getnames.otherstuff#</li> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</cfoutput>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use named anchors to jump to a location in your page.  Say you were jumping to a person's last name.

```
<cfset letters = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z">
<cfoutput>
    <cfloop list="#letters#" index="i">
        <a href="###i#">#i#</a>&nbsp;
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>

<cfset currentLetter = left(yourQuery.lastName,1)>
<cfoutput query = "yourQuery">
    <cfif currentLetter neq left(yourQuery.lastName,1)>
        <cfset currentLetter = left(yourQuery.lastName,1)>
        <a name = "#currentLetter#" />
    </cfif>
    #yourQuery.lastName#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: An easier way to loop from A to Z is to do <cfloop from="#ASC('A')#" to="#ASC('Z')#" index="Letter">, so you don't  have to type them all out. Use CHR(Letter) to get back to the letter.

Comment: Yep, that is definitely an option.

Comment: You could also just say from = "65" to = "90" seeing as the ascii A-Z is static, no need to evaluate the value every time.

Comment: The "evaluation" would be one time and unnoticeable. What you gain in readability is well worth the "performance" hit, at least in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Use anchors. In your list, give the first item with the starting letter an ID, like so:

```
<li id="letter-a">Apple</li>
```

Then link to it in your list of letters:

```
<a href="#letter-a">A</a>
```

(If you have headings for each letter, give the ID to those instead.)

Comment: Thanks, good answer. I forgot to mention that my list is populated using a query so I wouldn't be able to add a link to the list item beginning with a certain letter. Edited my question.

Comment: @Alias: Well, you're going to need to modify your query then. Can you post the code?

Comment: Alias, post code in [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13273321/edit) and it can be formatted properly. (Also, you just need to add the id to the first tr/td for each letter.)